# Put and Delete with CouchDB + Lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing, couchdb, dml

I'm running CouchDB (1.2.1) + Lucene on Linux (https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/), and I have a few questions.

I index everything - one index for all documents. i've got around 20.000.000 documents.

1. How fast are puts/deletes done on the index -- I have about 10-50 Puts/Deletes etc. a second.
2. Is there a rule, like after 10,000 updates you have to optimize the index?
3. Are changes in documents immediately visible in the index? If not is there a delay or a temporary table for this updates/deletes?

Thanks in advance - Brandon

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a profiler to measure the put/delete performance. That's the only way you'll get reasonably accurate numbers.
2. Optimization depends on how quickly the index is changing -- again, you will need to experiment and profile.
3. Changes are immediately visible in the index, but not to already-open IndexReaders.